# Keyboard shortcuts problem

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am using ubuntu 13.04 and just loving it.
I have assigned keyboard shortcut to quick shutdown. I found this method through google.

I created a custom shortcut through command

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --system --dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit 
    /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```

I have been trying to do the same to quick reboot but I can't find it anywhere on Google.

Please help, thanks in advance, I haven't got much knowledge of command line.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Manager.Restart`, used where you are using `Manager.Stop` for shutdown? See [ConsoleKit docs](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/ConsoleKit/doc/ConsoleKit.html#Manager.Restart).